# Yii2 Cannot get PendalF89/yii2-filemanager to work in backend

Tags: php, web-applications, configuration, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I cannot get [PendalF89/yii2-filemanager](https://github.com/PendalF89/yii2-filemanager) to work in my backend application.

I am using the improved advanced template which can be found [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-improved-advanced-template/)

Whenever I upload an image it goes to_protected/backend/uploads however I need the images to be publicly accessible for frontend and backend.

So the upload folder needs to be outside the protected folder however I cannot seem to set my filemanager config up to do so.

I need to change base path but I am not too sure what alias to use as it always seems to create a folder within the current app root such as
_protected/backend

Here is my current config:

```
'filemanager' => [
        'class' => 'pendalf89\filemanager\Module',
        // Upload routes
        'routes' => [
            // Base absolute path to web directory
            'baseUrl' => '',
            // Base web directory url
            'basePath' => '@webroot',
            // Path for uploaded files in web directory
            'uploadPath' => 'uploads',
        ],
        // Thumbnails info
        'thumbs' => [
            'small' => [
                'name' => 'Small',
                'size' => [100, 100],
            ],
            'medium' => [
                'name' => 'Medium',
                'size' => [300, 200],
            ],
            'large' => [
                'name' => 'Large',
                'size' => [500, 400],
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it's working with this setup.
The images will be in eg. "app-root/web/uploads/2015/07/" folder (Yii2 basic). Hope this helps to understand.

```
// Upload routes
    'routes' => [
        // Base absolute path to web directory
        'baseUrl' => '/web',
        // Base web directory url -- htdocs eg.
        'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
        // Path for uploaded files in web directory
        'uploadPath' => 'uploads',
    ],
```